# Copy file to multiple locations

Tags: java, copy

Is there an efficient way to copy a file in java to around 100 folders without having to use

```
private static void copyFileUsingJava7Files(File source, File dest)
       throws IOException {
   Files.copy(source.toPath(), dest.toPath());
}
```

100 times

Comment: What you deem to be inefficient about using `Files.copy`?

Comment: why not create 100 links to the same file?

Comment: What is it about the execution of your example code block that you wish were different ? 
Can you show what your data structures look like ? Actually calling the method is trivial, even doing it 100 times with a List of destinations. I assume there is some obstacle either structurally, or in performance, which you would like to avoid, but without more context I'm not sure how to answer

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a code sample for you but think the most efficient way would be to set up an Asynchronous operation to handle all the file copies.

You would still need to do something similar to what you have but it wouldn't wait for each one to complete like you would get with a standard loop.  Send them out there asynchronously and let the operating system handle all the juggling of the tasks to get things done in the quickest possible way.

In addition to this, if you are copying a single file to multiple locations, you can read the file into memory, then copy the in-memory file to the destination.  This will help avoid problems such as slow file reads and waiting for locked files that can happen when reading from disk.

Answer (score 0):

No other option will be efficient other than simply using copy method.